# Error in the insertion of array in c as it shows octal value inserted

Tags: c

How to add the value 09 in an array as it can't be inserted as it shows the value is octal value and can't be inseted then how can we insert it into the array is there any method..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void prin(int day, int year) {
    int data[3];
    data[0] = day;
    data[1] = 09;
    data[2] = year;
    printf("%d.%d.%d",data[0],data[1], data[2]);
}
void check(int year) {
    int day;
    if (1700 <= year && year <= 1917) {
        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            //printf("The year is leap year");
            day = 12;
            prin(day, year);
        }
        else {
            day = 13;
            prin(day, year);
        }
    }
    else {
    //printf("REached");
        if(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 == 0)) {
            //printf("Year is not leap");
            day = 13;
            prin(day, year);
        }
         else {
            day = 12;
            prin(day, year);
        }
    }
}
int main(void) {
    int year;
    //printf("Enter the value of the year");
    scanf("%d",&year);
    check(year);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is as follows :

```
Day_of_programmer.c: In function 'prin':
Day_of_programmer.c:7:15: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant
    7 |     data[1] = 09;
      |               ^~
```

Comment: Replace `09` with `9`.  Numbers preceded by `0` are in octal (like numbers prexeced with `0x` are in hexadecimal). And `9` is an invalid digit in octal, (like `G` is an invalid digit in hexadecimal)

Comment: You probably just want `data[1] = 9; printf("%d.0%d.%d",data[0],data[1], data[2]);` Notice I added the `0` in the `printf`.

Comment: Slightly off topic: The `prin` function is overly complicated. You don't need the `data` array at all, ikt's totally redundant. Just use `printf("%d.0%d.%d", day, 9, year)`. A part from that I don't know why you want to print a hard coded `09`.

Comment: @Mayankkumar learn about the `%d` specifier in `printf`. Use `%02d` if you want to print non significant zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your `prin` function should be:

```
void prin(int day, int year) {
    printf("%02d.%02d.%04d",day, 9, year);
}
```

But actually you probably want rather this at the end of the day, because it's pretty pointless to print a date with a fixed month:

```
void prin(int day, int month, int year) {
    printf("%02d.%02d.%04d", day, month, year);
}
```

- If you use `%d`, the number is printed without any non significant
  zeros.
- If you use `%02d`, the number will be printed with two digits,
  non significant digits will be replaced with `0`.
- If you use `%2d`, the number will be printed with two digits,
  non significant digits will be replaced by whitespac .

Read up the documentation of `printf`, especially the part dealing with the different variants of the `%d` format specifier.

Concerning the error message `error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant`, the other answer answers this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
data[1] = 09;
```

The leading `0` tells the compiler that it should expect an octal constant, which only contains the digits `0` through `7`.  Just get rid of the leading `0`:

```
data[1] = 9;
```

Then the compiler will treat it as an ordinary decimal value.

Comment: But sir I must have to print '0' in front of the '9'  then how can i , is there any function or something which can get rid of it.

Comment: @Mayankkumar You're confusing two different things:  (1) The value stored in `data[1]`, and (2) How it's printed.  Take a simpler example:  `05` is the value `5` in either octal or decimal, right?  And assigning `05` is *exactly* the same as assigning `5`.  There's only one integer with the value `5`.

Comment: @Mayankkumar   If you want to *print* it with a leading zero, then you need to use a format that zero-pads it to two digits.  You can use old-style formatting, e.g. `"%02d" % data[1]`, or you can use the new-style `format` method, e.g. `"{:02g}".format(data[1])`.  Either way will format the number `9` as a *string* with a leading zero.

Comment: @Mayankkumar Anyway, the specific question you asked was why you were getting a syntax error and how to fix it.  That's the question I answered.  You didn't ask how to format an integer as a 2-digit zero-padded string.